# Kendo chart showing wrong time data in X Axis

Tags: javascript, time, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

In my application, I need to show the time format in Kendo chart.
The following example demonstrates how to display time on the value axis of the categorical Kendo UI Charts. [Kendo Document for Display Time on Value Axis](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/various/display-time-on-value-axis)

Kendo UI Snippet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [{
      data: [new Date("2015/01/01 01:22").getTime(),
             new Date("2015/01/01 02:24").getTime()]
    }],
    valueAxis: {
      labels: {
        template: "#= kendo.format('{0:HH:mm}', new Date(value)) #"
      },
      min: new Date("2015/01/01").getTime(),
      majorUnit: 20 * 60 * 1000 // 20 minutes step
    },
    tooltip: {
      visible: true,
      template: "#= kendo.format('{0:HH:mm}', new Date(value)) #"
    }
  });
</script>
```

This showing time properly, but the problem is when the chart data as follows,

```
series: [{
  data: [new Date("2015/01/01 00:00").getTime(),
         new Date("2015/01/01 00:00").getTime()]
}],
```

When chart data as above (`00:00`), application getting stuck. How can I avoid this.

I changed `majorUnit` as `majorUnit: 0 * 60 * 1000`, Then an application load without stuck. but Axis data showing the wrong way(please look below image).

[image]

Comment: "application getting stuck" -  is there an error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @GaloisGirl No, there is no console error.

Comment: It seems to happen when both data points are equal. Pre-process your data, and/or file a bug with Kendo.

Comment: @GaloisGirl yeah, that was the reason, when all points are equal it happening. Thanks for your response.